# Handle a very large string in pl/sql script

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, clob

I am trying to run below code which reads the index definition for table A so that it can be created again after I delete/create that in this script. This script runs fine when the returned value(ddl) is small but in other environments where the value is large with 140K characters in one row this script fails with below mentioned error. Please note that I cannot use spool in this case due to some restrictions. Could someone help on how to resolve this issue or suggest some another approach?

Thanks in advance.

"An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2)."

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE 
my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
TYPE clob_array IS VARRAY(15) OF CLOB;
index_array clob_array := clob_array();
v_clob CLOB;
--index_array SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
BEGIN
OPEN my_cursor FOR 'select replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl (''INDEX'', index_name), ''"C",'', '''')
              from user_indexes
             where table_name = ''A''';

LOOP FETCH my_cursor INTO v_clob;
EXIT WHEN my_cursor%NOTFOUND;
index_array.extend;
index_array(index_array.count) := v_clob;
dbms_output.put_line(index_array(index_array.count));
END LOOP;
CLOSE my_cursor;
END;
/
```

Comment: I think the initialisation is proper but it is throwing exception at dbms_output.put_line. AS if I comment this line I do not get any exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simulated this issue you are getting this error because of the `dbms_output.put_line` which displays the output.Try switching to `UTL_FILE` at the server side OR Try for any [alternatives](https://blog.fatalmind.com/2009/11/11/pipelined-functions-better-then-dbms_output/index.html)

Comment: Yes that looks to be the issue. BTW does such a large query with characters more than 32K is supported in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE or not?

Comment: for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE only upto 32k only allowed

Comment: I tried this and executed the SQL with more than 32k characters using Execute Immediate and it worked fine. So you think it is DB version dependent?

Comment: I checked in asktom site where it was mentioned like that yeah it may be DB version Dependent

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the code can be simplified to:

```
declare
    type         clob_array is table of clob;
    index_array  clob_array := clob_array();
begin
    for r in (
        select replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX', index_name), '"C",') as index_ddl
        from   user_indexes
        where  table_name = 'A'
    )
    loop
        index_array.extend;
        index_array(index_array.count) := r.index_ddl;
        dbms_output.put_line(substr(index_array(index_array.count), 1, 32767));
    end loop;
end;
```

I used `substr()` to limit the value passed to `dbms_output.put_line` to its [documented limit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-CEC56D3F-3BA6-4CA0-8D53-E286AB6A0269). You could probably work around it by splitting the text into smaller chunks, and maybe finding the position of the last blank space before position 32767 in order to avoid splitting a word.

Here's what I came up with:

```
declare
    type         clob_array is table of clob;
    index_array  clob_array := clob_array();

    procedure put_line
        ( p_text clob )
    is
        max_len constant simple_integer := 32767;
        line varchar2(max_len);
        remainder clob := p_text;
    begin
        while dbms_lob.getlength(remainder) > max_len loop
            line := dbms_lob.substr(remainder,max_len);
            line := substr(line, 1, instr(line, ' ', -1));
            remainder := substr(remainder, length(line) +1);
            dbms_output.put_line(line);
        end loop;
        
        if length(trim(remainder)) > 0 then
            dbms_output.put_line(remainder);
        end if;
    end put_line;
begin
     for r in (
        select replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX', index_name), '"C",') as index_ddl
        from   user_indexes
        where  table_name = 'A'
    )
    loop
        index_array.extend;
        index_array(index_array.count) := r.index_ddl;
        put_line(index_array(index_array.count));
    end loop;
end;
```